# Select all records on entity with associated key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have two Entities, Plan and PricingTier.  The Plan maps to my plans table and has a column called pricing_tier_id.  This maps to the PricingTiers table via its id column.  The Entities have a manyToOne assocation from Plan to PricingTier, and a OneToMany association from PricingTier to Plan.  Those are below:

**Plan Entity**

```
etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\Plan:
  type: entity
  table: plans
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
      nullable: true
    description:
      type: text
      nullable: true
    termsConditions:
      column: terms_conditions
      type: text
      nullable: true
    active:
      type: boolean
      nullable: true
    amount:
      type: decimal
      nullable: true
      scale: 2
      precision: 5
    affinity:
      type: boolean
      nullable: true
    deactivationFee:
      column: deactivation_fee
      type: decimal
      scale: 2
      precision: 5
      nullable: true
    gracePeriodDays:
      column: grace_period_days
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    recurringInMonths:
      column: recurring_in_months
      type: integer
      nullable: true
    activeStartDate:
      column: active_start_date
      type: date
    activeEndDate:
      column: active_end_date
      type: date
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ prePersist ]
  manyToOne:
    pricingTier:
      targetEntity: PricingTier
      inversedBy: plans
      joinColumn:
        name: pricing_tier_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

**PricingTier Entity**

```
etrak\OnlineOrderProcessingBundle\Entity\PricingTier:
  type: entity
  table: pricing_tiers
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: 50
    description:
      type: string
      length: 100
      nullable: true
    minimumDevices:
      column: minimum_devices
      type: integer
    isAffinity:
      column: is_affinity
      type: boolean
    keyname:
      type: string
      length: 55
    createdBy:
      column: created_by
      type: string
      length: 20
    createdOn:
      column: created_on
      type: datetime
    updatedOn:
      column: updated_on
      type: datetime
      nullable: true
  lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ onPrePersist ]
    preUpdate: [ onPreUpdate ]
  oneToMany:
    plans:
      targetEntity: Plan
      mappedBy: pricingTier
  oneToOne:
    product:
      targetEntity: Product
      joinColumn:
        name: product_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

What I'm needing to do is the something like: SELECT * FROM plans WHERE pricing_tier_id = 2

I'd like to stay away from SQL/DQL if possible. Surely Doctrine has a built in way to do this?  Just to note, I'm using Doctrine as a bundle in Symfony 2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just find the pricing tier you want using the repository..

```
$pricingTier = $this->getDoctrine()
                    ->getRepository('OnlineOrderProcessingBundle:PricingTier')
                    ->find($id);
```

And then you've got access to all associated plans using..

```
$pricingTier->getPlans()
```

Or in twig

```
{{ pricingTier.plans }}
```

Comment: This worked great!  Thanks!  Once I opened the PricingTier.php Entity file I saw that there was a getPlans() method in there :)